# Using a cronjob to update and display results of a MySQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, node.js

Im having some trouble how I could realize it to have a dynamic website where the data is fetched via ajax to the user.

At the end of the ajax is a simple php script which opens a MySQL connection to my db and fetching some results (which looks to all users the same, there aren't any user specific results) to display them later for example in a table.

This is what I come so far. It is working but when there thousands of users who open the website ... this wouldn't be good and I don't think my server would update it fast enough.

So my intention is to update the wanted results only once every x seconds serversided with a cronjob maybe, I would save a lot resources.

The problem is that I don't know how I could realize this part, could I please get some help? Or should I forget the ajax stuff and start using node.js?

I've got a pretty good root server which is my webspace aswell so it would be possible to install some extra applications.

Comment: If you want to display same results every x mins - why not cache them, and refresh if needed? This way all you would need is this ajax call to save the data, which even with a lot of users hitting the site concurrently would be enough for mysql to handle. However, your question is still not clear - what node.js has to do with ajax? What kind of results do you want to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really basic Node.js solution using [`memory-cache`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache) and [`node-cron`](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron):

```
var cache = require('memory-cache');
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

var job;
var jobStarted = false;
var rateLimitExceeded = false;

var job = new CronJob('5 * * * * *', function() {
    // Runs every 5 seconds
    doALongDataBaseOperation(function(err, data) {
        cache.put('cacheId', data);
    });
});

app.get('/path/that/needs/caching', function(req, res) {
    cache.get('cacheId', function(e, data) {
        if (data) {
            res.end(data);
        } else {
            // contingency in case the cache doesn't exist
            doALongDataBaseOperation(function(err, data) {
                res.end(data);
                cache.put('cacheId', data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi remus, thank you for this fast answer.
Would this example cache the data every 5 seconds on every user?
So every user would see the update delayed from another user (even when it is just a second)?

Comment: Well, that depends how you set it up. The cache ID is what identifies the cache instance. You claim it's the same data for every user - if you set it up with a shared cache ID, then regardless of which user makes a request, they'll get the cached results. If you stored it using the user ID as the cache ID though, then it would be cached separately for each user.

Comment: It is 100% the same data which should be shown. For example a basic chat where every user should see the cached results (which we display with ajax) but the user is irrelevant when it depends on when to update the cache (every 5 sec). So I barely can ajax every nanoseconds without any MySQL query (the better the users bandwidth the faster he gets the update, almost live.. wouldn't it?) Can't I control the CronJob serversided instead of controlled by every user? I'm sorry if I understand something wrong.

Comment: This is a server-side example - you host your cache wrapped in Node.js and server up the cache to any user to makes a request.

Comment: Okay, now I understood. But wait when I use Node.js to update cache the results, isn't there a better way to force refresh the result to the user then instead of running my 'user -> php -> ajax -> result ' ? Like the Node.js is talking to the user in this example: ' Node.js -> user -> result'? I hope it doesn't look weird to you but I try to get some more understanding into this and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No, the flow would be User -> Node.js -> Database, or User -> Browser -> AJAX -> Node.js -> Database. If you have PHP in there, that's OK too, it would sit in between Node and your db probably.

Comment: So then my AJAX part would be useless when I can put my PHP stuff into the Node.js and I could update in real time instead of AJAX fetch where every user would have another delay (the cache of course). Or do you know a better solution?

Comment: Node.js is a server though - so you're not updating in realtime, you're just providing an alternative means of accessing the data. Node.js _serves_ data just as PHP would when connecting to a database. Whether that makes your PHP useless is up to you, but it wouldn't make AJAX calls from the browser useless (since I suspect your PHP probably serves data in JSON format already).

Answer (score 0):

You could cache the data using Memcache (or something similar). Your cronjob could run and refresh the cache as often as you would like.

Then your AJAX can call a simple PHP script to retrieve the data from your cache.